# Swift Dispatch Source Timer doesn't fire as scheduled

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a timer declared as the following:

```
var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
    timer!.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now() + .seconds(60), interval: .seconds(3600), leeway: .seconds(1))
    timer!.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        self?.saveData()
    }
    timer!.resume()
    print("TIMER HAS STARTED")
}
```

This code is executed in my `viewDidLoad` method, and fires correctly the first time after the 1 min delay I included. It is then supposed to fire every hour. I ran my app in the simulator keeping it constantly on and in focus. In fact it is still running.

The first time the data was saved I logged a time of 11:45am. It was not saved again until 1:00pm, and then at 2:08. What am I missing?

EDIT: When testing this timer I was able to get data every minute, but for the actual application I need it to do it every hour.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the `DispatchSourceTimer` does not fire the event when I make an instance of it inside the `viewDidLoad`, not really sure why, tried it multiple times.

So just make sure you have your `DispatchSourceTimer` as a `property`, and also you could just try to shorten the `interval` and the `delay` parameter of the `DispatchSourceTimer`'s schedule for the sake of testing, like so:

```
// MARK: - Properties

var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!

// MARK: - Functions
// MARK: Overrdes

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
    timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), repeating: .seconds(5), leeway: .seconds(1))
    timer.setEventHandler(handler: { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.saveData()
    })

    timer.resume()
}

func saveData() {
    print("❇️Invoked...")
}
```

Comment: Sorry my code was misleading at first, the timer is declared outside of viewDidLoad(). And when I set the interval to 60 seconds it works fine. I noticed you have `repeating` instead of `interval`, could that be the issue?

Comment: Actually it says that constructor doesn't exist, and I suspect it is because my timer is a `Dispatch Source` timer and not the regular `Timer`

Comment: Take note that this code was made using Xcode 9, thus it's a Swift 4.0. We both are using `DispatchSourceTimer`.